# How to set Hibernate MySQL Connection in Openshift Tomcat 7 (JBOSS EWS 2.0)?

Tags: mysql, spring, hibernate, maven, openshift

I'm developing Java based web application using spring hibernate and am trying out OpenShift to deploy my application. But I am facing troubles in configuring my application for the MySQL connector. I have included mysql-connector in my Maven dependency.

Below is my maven's `pom.xml` file's mysql dependency code:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.25</version>
    </dependency>
```

And here is my servlet-xml code:

```
<beans:bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <beans:property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <beans:property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST:$OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT/jbossews" />
    <beans:property name="username" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_USERNAME}" />
    <beans:property name="password" value="${OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PASSWORD}" /> 
</beans:bean>
```

But when I deploy this to my openshift account and hit the address of my controller, it shows the below error:

> HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.transaction.CannotCreateTransactionException:
>   Could not open Hibernate Session for transaction; nested exception is
>   org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Could not open
>   connection

I must be misconfiguring my MySQL stuff in xml file.

Comment: The `url` value seems to be missing curly brackets for expanding the environment variables. Also note, that JBoss EWS 2.0 comes with [pre-configured data sources](https://developers.openshift.com/servers/tomcat/ds.html) for MySQL and PostgreSQL; see the `.openshift/config/context.xml`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got an answer:

```
${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_HOST}:${env.OPENSHIFT_MYSQL_DB_PORT}/${env‌​.OPENSHIFT_APP_NAME}
```

these are the OpesnShift variables. you cant use them for configuration. They should be replaced by their real values which you have done for the first one.